# How to set JSP variable in tag to read with <%= viewEditPromotionURL>?

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I was thinking such variable can only be set by Java code:

```
<%
    String viewEditPromotionURL="http://promotion.info";
%>
```

but I found that it can also be set in custom tag:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="editPromotion" var="editPromotionURL" />
```

How tag can set variable visible by `<%=...>`?

Can me myself do this? For example:

```
<%
   String variableName = "myvariable";
   String variableValue = "myvalue";
   // secret part to store myvalue into myvariable
%>

<p>Variable = <%= myvariable%></p>
```

Is this possible? What to write in the secret part?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output from Jasper (the JSP Compiler), the `<%= myvariable %>` tag is converted to:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
out.print(myvariable);
```

This means `myvariable` must be defined somewhere `public void _jspService(final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, final javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)` can see it.  Your only options are either inside the JSP page like your first code snipit, or at the class level using `<%! %>`.  In the `<portlet:>` example you are using a taglib to add variables which you can learn more about [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags4.html#wp89646).

Comment: Can you please provide some hints or links about how JSP variables can be defined in taglibs?

Comment: Thanks, but this is about EL variable which is accessible by `${myvariable}`. How to define variables, which are accessible by `<%=myvariable>`?